# The newer version of Adobe AIR can't play video in plain HTML?

Tags: video, air

The November 2008 version can play video embedded in plain HTML pages (like YouTube).
The newest version can't.

Is there any workaround to this problem?

Comment: are you sure this isn't something local to your computer?

Comment: yeah, it turns out that I need to turn off compiz (I was using Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested using an HTML control in an AIR application to view YouTube. I could view the videos just fine.

I am using the Flex 4 SDK with the Flash Builder Beta.